# Fetching numbers from contacts using content resolver query - special case

Tags: java, android, sql, regex, sqlite

I am trying to query phone number stored in the contacts database of android.

I am providing an input sting for comparison and I need the query to pick only those rows which matches this input string.

While querying the contacts db, I would like the query to ignore all the special characters contained in a number and compare the input string with only the digits contained in the field.

eg; if the stored number is (944) 6-129-337 , the query should compare the input string with 9446129337 and not with (944) 6-129-337 .

Following is the code with which I query the db and fetch the numbers.

```
            contactCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND " +
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " LIKE ? ",new String[] { input_string }, null);
```

The problem I have here is, it just does a plain search in each phone number field without internally removing(using regexp or modifying the query?) the special characters.

I do not know how to do that cleaning up of special characters inside query. Any help in this regard which would help me resolve this query issue will be well appreciated

Thanks,
Anees

Answer (score 1):

As a hack that may work for you... you could pass your number using wildcards between every digit, and then re-filter the results in your Java code... e.g. `... LIKE '%9%4%4%6%1%2%9%3%3%7%' ...` is liable to return very few results, including `(944) 6-129-337` and (perhaps) `+1 (944) 612-9337`; but you can collect these results, strip the non-digit values in your own code, and compare them. If you have very short search strings, though, your number of "false positive" hits will be much greater. Unfortunately, I haven't tested this with the Android content system, so it's plausible that you could overflow the number of wildcard characters permitted, or similar :-(

Comment: It worked for few tests I performed.. thanks for the help BRPocock . I really look forward to what android people say about this.

Comment: Just don't accidentally pump `'%1%'` into a phonebook with 5,000 records :-) (especially an American phonebook, with 5,000 `+1` prefixes)

Comment: then I guess, I should not be using this, as I foresee chances of encountering a phonebook with more than 1000 entries. Any altrnate methods?

Comment: Just be sure that your user input is long enough to make up a valid phone number, before adding the wildcards. I believe(?) no locale has phone numbers of less than 6 digits, which should at least seriously reduce the risk of a runaway selection. The only counter-examples I can think of are if users have SMS short codes or certain types of emergency (911, 999) or service (411,611) numbers in their phonebooks, but hopefully you aren't interested in finding those?

Comment: that would not be  an issue in my case

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/phones/filter/%915894%");
```

Return Only your need.